# Wordpress getChildren using to make an menu

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is: i Want to make my own Menubar that looks like this: [image]

As you can see the buttons on the top are FIXED (these are the 6 Parents in which the Pages can get)

If you press on the green button the submenuitems appear. Now - if you press on the submenuitem the submenu should appear under the specific submenuitem. In html it's easy:

But now I need the subsubitem of the pages via php in this "format".

```
<div class="menuitem" id="info">     <a href="#"><img src="./information.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></a></div>

<div id="infosub">
                <div onClick="hoverSubMenu('infosub1')" class="submenu">submenuitem1</div>
                <div id="infosub1" class="subsubmenu">
                    <div class="subsubitem">test1.1</div>
                    <div class="subsubitem">test1.2</div>
                    <div class="subsubitem">test1.3</div>
                    <div class="subsubitem">test1.4</div>
                    <div class="subsubitem">test1.5</div>
                </div>

                <div onClick="hoverSubMenu('infosub2')" class="submenu">submenuitem2</div>

                <div id="infosub2" class="subsubmenu">
                    <div class="subsubitem">test2.1</div>
                </div>

                <div onClick="hoverSubMenu('infosub3')" class="submenu">submenuitem3</div>
                <div id="infosub3" class="subsubmenu">
                </div> 
            </div>
```

Anyone knows what I trying?

(getting the things opened and closed are no problems - the problem is only how can I get the subpages of a specific page and then also the subpages of THIS subpage and then getting it into this format)

I tried it myself like this:

```
<?php
                // Set up the objects needed
                $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

                // Get the page as an Object
                $information =  get_page_by_title('Information');

                // Filter through all pages and find Information's children
                $information_children = get_page_children( $information->ID, $all_wp_pages );

                // echo what we get back from WP to the browser
                echo '<div onClick="hoverSubMenu("infosub1")" class="submenu">' . print_r( $information_children, true ) . '</div>';

                echo '<div id="infosub1" class="subsubmenu">';
                echo '<div class="subsubitem">' ...
```

But there is the problem that it will show EVERY submenuitem and then show EVERY subsubmenuitem - not like in the html 1.submenuitem 1.1 subsubitem 1.2. subsubitem then 2. submenuitem 2.1. submenuitem...

Comment: without visiting the demo, hard to tell only reading the text

Comment: At the moment it's a html page and i'm trying to get this into a wordpress template so there is only the html-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is details description to handle with wordpress menu. please try this link, it will help you. [Change static nav menu to wordpress dynamic menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781414/change-static-nav-menu-to-wordpress-dynamic-menu/19782040#19782040)

I can give you some clues but you have to do a lot of stuff. Please check the following code which displays child page title in `<ul><li><a href=""` current page:

```
$args = array(
                'sort_order' => 'ASC',
                'sort_column' => 'post_title',
                'hierarchical' => 1,
                'exclude' => '',
                'include' => '',
                'meta_key' => '',
                'meta_value' => '',
                'authors' => '',
                'parent' => get_the_ID(), // it takes the current page id
                'exclude_tree' => '',
                'number' => '',
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
            $pages = get_pages($args);
            foreach($pages as $page){
                $allPages .= '<li><a href="">'.$page->post_title.'</a></li>';
            }
            echo '<ul>'.$allPages.'</ul>';
```

It will help you to further solution.

Comment: thanks but - that's not my problem - i want to make the first part -> static and the second part (submenu & subsubmenu) -> dynamic with the architecture i posted above